# How can I add margin to Bootstrap table rows?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

in a striped table I want to add extra space between two rows without the strip color change. After the 1st sum row I need an extra space before the 2nd data block starts. Unfortunately the mb-3 wont work on the tr element. What is the good solution for a problem like this?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr class="mb-3">
```

Thanks for your suggestions!
Code sample can be found: https://www.codeply.com/p/kU5U99YOKU

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mb-3">
      <td><strong>Sum of data1</strong></td>
      <td>sum1</td>
      <td>sum1</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- as the mb-3 wont work I added this but this is wrong -->
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Sum of data3</strong></td>
      <td>sum2</td>
      <td>sum2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple tbody elements, which may be a more semantically correct approach. Use borders as spacers:

```css
tbody {
  border-bottom: 20px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mb-3">
      <td><strong>Sum of data1</strong></td>
      <td>sum1</td>
      <td>sum1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Sum of data3</strong></td>
      <td>sum2</td>
      <td>sum2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mb-3">
      <td><strong>Sum of data1</strong></td>
      <td>sum1</td>
      <td>sum1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Sum of data3</strong></td>
      <td>sum2</td>
      <td>sum2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your strategy of using spacer rows can work, but you'll want to hide them from assistive technology using `aria-hidden` attributes:

```css
.spacer td {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mb-3">
      <td><strong>Sum of data1</strong></td>
      <td>sum1</td>
      <td>sum1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer" aria-hidden="true">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Sum of data3</strong></td>
      <td>sum2</td>
      <td>sum2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer" aria-hidden="true">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mb-3">
      <td><strong>Sum of data1</strong></td>
      <td>sum1</td>
      <td>sum1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer" aria-hidden="true">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Sum of data3</strong></td>
      <td>sum2</td>
      <td>sum2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wooo never heard about multiple tbody-s. Hm. Is it html compatible? Then it sounds great!

Comment: Tried the multiple tbody, but there is no extra gap between them. Added <tbody class="mb-3"> but did nothing.

Comment: It uses other styles than the bs standards. Cannot be solved using the pre-defined styles?

Comment: I've never done a Bootstrap project that didn't have a custom stylesheet loaded. Bootstrap isn't a magic "do everything" wand. If that's a concern you should make it more clear in your question post.

Comment: Your two answers solved the problem. Multiple tbody (to reset the row colors) and a spacer style together is a good solution. Thanks for your time!